# Installed Avast! in Pangolin

Tags: 12.04

What will avast! do after installed in Pangolin?

Firstly, I think Avast! will do the same thing as it did in Windows.
* Automatically updated
* Automatically scan every device, which plugged via USB

But my Ubuntu Avast! do nothing.
Is it normal? Or what should I do to make it works?
Please guide me ...

**NB:**
I just installed > update > and do scan manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can update Avast, by using the Update Database button in the top-left-hand corner, or you can also go Tools --> Update Database.

Under Tools --> Preferences, you can also set it to install updates automatically.